# Buscar valor em input javascript

Tags: javascript

Opa,

Acredito que deva ser simples, mas, não consegui um funcionamento perfeito.

Tenho uma função que ao ser clicada deve verificar o valor contido em um input text, os valores estão separados por uma `/` e são inteiros. Preciso que quando essa função seja executada, ela envie um valor inteiro e verifique se este valor está contido no input, caso esteja, deverá remove-lo, caso não, deverá incluílo, tentei assim:

```
var opcoes_selecionadas = document.getElementById("options_add_input").value;

if(opcoes_selecionadas.search("/"+opcao_id+"/")){
   alert('string encontrada');
}
else
{
   opcoes_selecionadas = opcoes_selecionadas + "/" + opcao_id;
   document.getElementById("options_add_input").value = opcoes_selecionadas;
}
```

Mas, não está funcionando.

Answer (score 3):

```js
/**
  * @param String input - O id do input com o valor a ser adicionado/removido.
  * @param String output - O id do input com a lista atual de valores.
  *
  * @return void
  *
  **/
function doIt(input, output){

    // Guarda os textos.
    var i = document.getElementById(input).value;
    var o = document.getElementById(output).value;

    // Divide a lista em um array e busca o elemento em input.
    var a = o.split('/');
    var p = a.indexOf(i); 

    // Remove se o elemento existe. Adiciona do contrário.
    if(p > -1)
        a.splice(p, 1); 
    else
        a.push(i.toString());

    // Atualiza a lista com a união do array.
    document.getElementById(output).value = a.join('/');
}
```

```html
<label>Entrada</label>
<input type="text" id="entrada" />
<label>Lista</label>
<input type="text" id="lista" />
<button onclick="doIt('entrada', 'lista');">Adicionar/Remover</button>
```

No seu botão apenas chame a função com os `id`s dos `input`s:

```
<button onclick="doIt('opcao', 'options_add_input');"></button>
```

Comment: Opa amigão, desculpa a demora em responder, mas, ao inserir o código, está adicionando normalmente, mas, não remove, a var `p` está sempre retornando -1, ou seja, mesmo contendo o valor no input está sendo adicionado. 

Ao fazer o `var p = o.indexOf(i); `, ou seja, o indexof diretamente na var do input ele retorna a posição do valor no input, mas, não remove, apenas não adiciona.

Poderia me dar uma força amigão?

Abraço

Comment: Adicionado snippet funcional. Talvez a versão do seu browser não suporte o `indexOf`; verifique.

Answer (score 2):

Olá,
não sei se eu entendi muito bem, mas vou tentar ajudar, fiz a seguinte função:

```js
document.getElementById('send').onclick = function() {
  checkNumber(300);
}

function checkNumber(number) {
  var options = document.getElementById("options_add_input").value;
  // Transforma o valor recebido do input em um array
  var arrOptions = options.split('/').map(function(item) {
        // Converte os valores em inteiros
  return parseInt(item, 10);
  });
  
  // Verifica se número recebido está no array, se não estiver é adicionado e se estiver é removido
  var index = arrOptions.indexOf(number);
  if (index == -1) {
   arrOptions.push(300);
  } else {
   arrOptions.splice(index, 1);
  }
  
  console.log(arrOptions);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="options_add_input">
<button id="send">Send</button>
```

Comment: Podias usar `var arrOptions = options.split('/').map(Number);`, e comprimir mais um pouco https://jsfiddle.net/Lp7L9vuk/, mas acho que a ideia que o AP precisa é essa.